# Deployment strategy for golang app, how to run golang app on production

Tags: go, deployment

I have a golang web app, and I need to deploy it. I am trying to figure out the best practice on how to run a golang app on production. The way I am doing it now, very simple,

- just upload the built binary to production, without actually having
  the source code on prod at all.

However I found an issue, my source code actually reads a `config/<local/prod>.yml` config file from the source. If I just upload the binary without source code, the app cant run because it is missing config. So I wonder what is the best practice here.

I thought about a couple solutions:

- Upload source code, and the binary or build from the source
- Only upload the binary and the config file.
- Move `yml config` to `Env Variables`, but I think with this solution, the code will be less structured, because if you have lots of configs, env variables will be hard to manage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A) Do not upload source code. B) Use env variables for setting specific to the _environment_ (not arbitrary "config" options). C) Get rid of unnecessary configurations. D) have sane defaults for all "configurations". E) Consider baking in "configurations" during  a production build. F) Provide a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most common deployment strategy for an app is trying to comply with the 12-factor-app [methodology](https://12factor.net/).

So, in this case, if your YAML file is the configuration file, then it would be better if you put the configuration on the Environment Variables(ENV vars). So that when you deploy your app on the container, it is easier to config your running instance from the ENV vars rather than copying a config file to the container.

However, while writing system software, it is better to comply with the file system hierarchy structure defined by the OS you are using. If you are using a Unix-like system you could read the hierarchy structure by typing `man hier` on the terminal. Usually, I install the compiled binary on the `/usr/local/bin` directory and put the configuration inside the `/usr/local/etc`.

For the deployment on the production, I created a simple Makefile that will do the building and installation process. If the deployment environment is a bare metal server or a VM, I commonly use Ansible to do the deployment using ansible-playbook. The playbook will fetch the source code from the code repository, then build, compile, and install the software by running the `make` command.

If the app will be deployed on containers, I suggest that you create an image and use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) so the source code and other tools that needed while building the binary would not be in the production environment and the image size would be smaller. But, as I mentioned before, it is a common practice to read the app configuration from the ENV vars instead of a config file. If the app has a lot of things to be configured, the file could be copied to the image while building the image.

Answer (score 3):

Good practice for deployment is to have reproducible build process that runs in a clean room (e.g. Docker image) and produces artifacts (binaries, configs, assets) to deploy, ideally also runs some tests that prove nothing was broken from the last time.

It is a good idea to package service - binary and all its needed files (configs, auxiliary files such as systemd, nginx or logrotate configs, etc.) into some sort of package - be it package native to your target environment Linux distribution (DPKG, RPM), virtual machine image, docker image, etc. That way you (or someone else tasked with deployment) won't forget any files, etc. Once you have package you can easily verify and deploy using native tools for that packaging format (`apt`, `yum`, `docker`...) to production environment.

For configuration and other files I recommend to make software to read it from well known locations or at least have option to pass paths in command line arguments. If you deploy to Linux I recommend following [LFHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html) (tldr; configuration to `/etc/yourapp/`, binaries to `/usr/bin/`)

It is not recommended to build the software from source in production environment as build requires tools that are normally unnecessary there (e.g. `go`, `git`, dependencies, etc.). Installing and running these requires more maintenance and might cause security and performance risks. Generally you want to keep your production environment minimal as required to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

While we wait for the [proposal: `cmd/go`: support embedding static assets (files) in binaries](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35950) to be implemented (see the [current proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35950#issuecomment-661926816)), you can use one of the embedding static asset files tools listed in that proposal.

The idea is to include your static file in your executable.
That way, you can distribute your program without being dependent on your sources.